# Wordpress Jquery on click

Tags: jquery, wordpress

registro un archivo script.js en mi functions.php a través de enqueque

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dcms_insertar3_js');
// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
function dcms_insertar3_js(){
    wp_register_script('dcms_miscript3',get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/script3.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('dcms_miscript3');
}
```

El archivo script3.js contiene lo siguiente

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    jQuery("#categoria1-productos .elementor-gallery-title").click(function() {
       console.log("click");
    });
});
```

El problema es que ingresa al click sin que se haga click, es decir, refresco la página y en consola me aparece "click", es decir está ingresando sin que le dé la orden

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizá debas cambiar la versión. Depurar `.js` y `.css` en WP es un dolor de cabeza, porque cada vez que cambias algo, debes cambiar la versión del archivo, de lo contrario, se seguirá ejecutando la versión anterior que esté en caché. Puedes probar a setear la versión manualmente y si estás trabajando con varios archivos deberías pensar en una solución automática, como cambiar la versión con la última fecha/hora de modificación del archivo o algo similar. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/269736) si te interesa algo así.

Comment: Prueba con algo como esto jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', '#categoria1-productos .elementor-gallery-title', function(){
  console.log( 'Click' );
 });
});